# How do I write test case for a function which uses uuid using sinon in typescript framework(loopback)?

Tags: typescript, uuid, sinon, loopback, testcase

//  this is the tc part which is causing problem:

```
  it('invokes some function', async () => {
     res = await client.post('/xyz').send(request).expect(200);
    expect(res.body).to.containEql(Response); //Response is some constant value in json format
  })
})
```

// function which is getting called is :

```
fun(){
   let id = uuid();
   let res = {
     "id": id,
     "xyz": xyz,
     "abc" : abc
   }
   
   return res;
}
```

Comment: You can mock / stub the uuid if you expect fixed value for test purpose only.
Example how to mock/stub: https://gist.github.com/skratchdot/cc48e529029850873f87

Comment: Which package provides the `uuid()` function?

Comment: @ slideshowp2  package is -  uuidv4